# What is a verb for something being the antithesis of something else?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs

I want to communicate that something is *being* the exact opposite, or the "antithesis" of something else.

For example:

> The ice `<antithesis verb>` the fire

Words I've thought of that come close in meaning, but don't fit:

- juxtaposes
- inverts
- contrasts

Comment: You could say *"Ice is **antithetical to** fire"*

Comment: The verb 'antithesise' is given in Wiktionary, but with the meaning 'create antitheses' not 'be antithetical to'. I'd avoid it totally.

Comment: Unfortunately this one sentence doesn't give us enough information about the sense of opposition. "Conflicts with" or "complements" might work in different senses, but without more context, we might have to go with a generic "opposes".

Comment: Agreed, it's too context dependent. A more left field option might be *ice balances fire*.

Comment: 1.Countervails 2.Nullifies

Comment: Is ***diametrically opposed***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**contradict**

to be contrary or opposed to; go against:

> Fire contradicts ice.

Read more at http://www.yourdictionary.com/contradict

Comment: I like this better than "counteracts." Marking as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**"counteracts"** comes to mind.

> - from [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counteract) -  "neutralize the usually ill effects of by means of an opposite force, action, or influence"

Ice counteracts fire.  Not always though.  As [**Frost**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_(poem)) has stated figuratively, in his most popular poem, both fire and ice are great for destruction.

Comment: That's a good one. Might mark this as the accepted depending on what else is suggested.

Answer (score -1):

How about "The ice is antagonistic to the fire"?

Comment: **Don't leave signatures under your post**, especially if they contain spammy links.